Getting 404 error in Golang while sending get request to a route
I am beginner in Golang and following let's go book. I create a servemux instance in the app and register root route with wildcard route pattern. I try to access the route and I am getting 404 page not found error. Without the wildcard route pattern it is working fine. Below is my code. What is wrong after adding wildcard route pattern?
package main

import ( 
    "log"
    "net/http"
)
func home(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    w.Write([]byte("Hello from Snippetbox"))
}
func main() {

    mux := http.NewServeMux()
    mux.HandleFunc("GET /{$}", home)

    log.Print("starting server on :4000")
    err := http.ListenAndServe(":4000", mux)
    log.Fatal(err) 
}


What HTTP path are you trying to access in your tests? /{$} means that the handler will be invoked exclusively on / — not /foo or any other descendant. If that's what you're doing, check the output of go version. Wildcard enhancements were only made in 1.22. Docs: https://pkg.go.dev/net/http#ServeMux

whats that ( /{$} ) wildcard ??

Was accessing "/" only. That was version issue.

I also encountered the same issue. After several times of ineffective rollback, I noticed that the go.mod file doesn't existed. So, I ran the following command to create go.mod, which should be located in Chapter 2.1.
go mod init snippetbox.alexedwards.net

And the program reply "Hello from Snippetbox" as expected.
Note:
I run the code samples via debugging in visual studio code and go version is go1.22.2.

In my case the go.mod was not missing, but the version therein was an old 1.19. I ended up changing the version in go.mod, and the code started working.

I was using an older version of go that was not supporting these functionality.. only after version 1.22.2 supports method routing and wild card entries.

I resolved the very same issue by setting the go.mod version to 1.22.x.
